# cerbero git am fails for gst-rtsp-server

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I need to do few changes in gst-rtsp-server-1.0 and generate android binaries.
I have followed below steps in Linux sytem:
$git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero

$./cerbero-uninstalled -c config/cross-android-universal.cbc bootstrap

$./cerbero-uninstalled -c config/cross-android-universal.cbc build gst-rtsp-server

Till here build is successful.

Now I changed rtsp-mount-points.c in path :
build/sources/android_universal/arm64/gst-rtsp-server-1.0-1.19.1.1/gst/rtsp-server/ and created patch file

Next created new directory in recipes as gst-rtsp-server-1.0 and kept the patch file here

Added this patch file in recipes/gst-rtsp-server-1.0.recipe file as below:

patches = [gst-rtsp-server-1.0/0001-test.patch]

Again when triggered build, getting below error:

Running command ['git', 'am', '--ignore-whitespace', '/home/user/cerbero/recipes/gst-rtsp-server-1.0/0001-test.patch']
Patch format detection failed.

Can anyone guide what is going wrong.

Comment: Another approach I tries is by cloning local repo :
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server
Followed steps as per:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/building-from-source-using-cerbero.html?gi-language=c#build-a-single-project-with-gstreamer
But I cant find autogen.sh after cloning

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve git am error while application of patch by creating patch using git format-patch command.